# How convert DateMask to style  in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have some custom DateMask as example 'yyyy/MM/dd'.
How can I get **style** from this DateMask for function **CONVERT( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )** ?

Maybe available some converting functions already?

PS. Variant as CONVERT( datetime, '2012/07/14', 111) is not flexible for me.

I want next realization if this possible

```
CONVERT( datetime, '2012/07/14', getStyleFromMask('yyyy/MM/dd'))
```

Comment: Go to the documentation for SQL Server (I just google "sql server cast convert"), look over the table, and find the one that you need.

Comment: There is no built in function for this but you could easily create your own using the table from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Using style 111 will convert from a 'yyyy/mm/dd' date format.
eg

```
select convert(datetime, '2012/07/14', 111)
```